# Consuming REST (GET) Service from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone Development. I want to make a HTTP request to REST(GET) service from my code. The result will be in Json.

I want get my result Asynchronously and while retriving I want to show Progress Ring.

Help me solving this. Thanks in Advance.

I tried following code. But getting exception

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147417842
  Message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressRing.put_IsActive(Boolean value)
       at eBooks.MainPage.GetResultCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
       at MS.Internal.Modern.ClientHttpWebRequest.c__DisplayClass1e.b__1c(Object state2)
  InnerException:
```

```
public void MakeRequest(string requestUrl)
{
    try
    {
        SearchProgress.IsActive = true;
        SearchButton.IsEnabled = false;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.BeginGetResponse(GetResultCallBack, request);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

private void GetResultCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request!=null)
    { 
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            if (response!=null)
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BookSearch));
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
                ebook = objResponse as BookSearch;
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            SearchProgress.IsActive = false;
            SearchButton.IsEnabled = true;
            DataLoaded(ebook);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what's not working with what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception describes what the problem is. You are trying to access SearchProgress control which is a ProgressRing created on a UI thread from a non-UI thread. In order to fix this, you need to make the change from the UI thread, and for that you need the use the CoreWindow dispatcher:

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm on UI thread");
        SearchProgress.IsActive = false;
        SearchButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
);
```